# Segmentation fault in String copy function strcpy in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char temp[4][10],wc[10];
    int i=0,j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ip.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%s",wc);
    while(strcmp(wc,"\n"))
    {
        strcpy(temp[i],wc);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",wc);
        i++;
    }

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%s",temp[j]);
    }
}
```

Output: `segmentation fault(core dumped)`

ip.txt contains:

```
LOOP ADD AREG,A
 SUB B,A
```

Where is the error?

Comment: `char *temp[4]` --> `char temp[4][10];` Also `fscanf(fp,"%s", wc);` need in loop. and `wc` does not include newline(`\n`).

Comment: above correction also gives segmentation fault

Comment: `strcmp(wc,"\n")` never become `0`. So `temp[i++]` occurs out of bounds.

Comment: Then try `char temp[4][50]; char wc[50]'` Your whole problem is that your buffers overflow, so either make them larger or use an input function with bounds checking (not the`%s` specifier).

Comment: `LOOP ADD AREG,A` seems to be more then just 10 characters ... right?

Comment: @alk It seems like the OP is trying to read 4 strings separated by spaces per line, so 10 would be enough then.

Answer (score 2):

My friends, after watching your question, I find that you mistakenly wrote `j` into `i` in the final loop of your program. For `i == 4`, the array `temp[]` will proceed to cross the border, which will lead to the segmentation fault.The way to deal is to replace i with j in the final loop, and `strcmp(wc,"\n")` never become 0 in the first loop, so `temp[]` will also cross the border.To be honest, I advice you to write down the desire in the question next time.And it is also dangerous to copy `wc` into the elements of the array of pointers, especially before you allocate space for them, this is also the reason to cause segmentation fault.

Comment: Politest answer ever.

Comment: i am copying string named wc into empty string pointed by temp[i]

Comment: "And it is also dangerous to copy wc into the elements of the array of pointers" `temp` is **not** an array of pointers. So this (not allocating space) is not the reason for segFault here.

Answer (score 2):

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",wc);
```

`%s` will match a sequence of non-white-space characters and will store that sequence at `wc`. Now since `\n` *is* a white-space character this call will ignore it!

So `wc` will never be equal to `\n`.

Therefore, `while(strcmp(wc,"\n")` is an infinie loop as the `strcmp` will never return `0`. (Even when the end of file `ip.txt` is reached!)

The statement `i++` will at some point make `i` greater than `4` (array limit) and that's when you get the segmentation fault. (Saves you from an infinite loop though!)

---

Other issues:

1. `fscanf(fp,"%s",wc);`
   Now what if a sequence of non-white-space characters is greater than `9` characters? `fscnaf` will store that sequence **and** an addiotional `\0` byte at the end of it, overwriting the buffer `wc` (size is 10, remember?)
   To avoid buffer overruns always use `maximum field width` with `%s`. e.g.

   ```
   fscanf(fp,"%9s",wc);
   ```
2. `fp=fopen("ip.txt","r");`
   Now how do you know that `fopen` succeded? Always check whether `fp` is `NULL` before doing any processing with `fp` e.g.

   ```
   if(fp=fopen("ip.txt","r"))
   {
       //`fp` code goes here
   }
   else
       printf("fopen failed!\n");
   ```

---

Solution:
You haven't mentioned but if your aim is to store the words from just a single line in an array `temp`, do processing and then again store the words from next line in an array `temp` then you can use `fgets()` to fetch a line in a buffer. And then using `sscanf()` to retrieve each word from that buffer to store them in `temp` array.

Something like:

```
char buffer[50], temp[4][10], *buf, *wc;
int i;

while(fgets(buffer, 50, stdin) != NULL)
{
    i = 0;
    buf = buffer;
    while((wc = strtok(buf, " \n")) && (i < 4))
    {
        strcpy(temp[i++], wc);
        if (buf && i)
            buf = NULL;
    }

    // process words here

}
```

Comment: `while((sscanf(buffer, "%9s", wc) == 1) && (i < 4))` : `wc` is same in this loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm sorry I didn't get it. Yes, `wc` is same. What difference does it make?

Comment: In case of `LOOP ADD AREG,A` it must be as follows `temp[0]`: `LOOP`, `temp[1]`: `ADD`, `temp[2]`: `AREG,A`,

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Umm not sure what do you mean by that. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: `buffer` does not change during the loop, and the position to take out is the same, so `wc` will have the same result. see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/sLJ3fu)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh! Now I understood! Thanks! I'll update my code later though.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Sorry, it got delayed but I believe bug is fixed now. Thanks! :)